# which file is executed first in pytest?

Tags: python, unit-testing, pytest

going through some tutorial about `pytest`. I have learned that

```
python -m pytest
```

this command executed the all file start with prefix `test_` as well as function which files are located in same directory. But my question is which file is executed first if the files are `test_app_id.py`, `test_sum.py`, `test_average.py`, `test_multiply.py`.

Comment: Serious question: why is this important to you? Are you relying on side effects from one test in the next? If so, that's a bad test methodology.

Comment: @AryaMcCarthy Thanks. This question comes from my knowing curiosity.

Comment: @AryaMcCarthy why is this so bad? what if some function reads output stored on the disk that was produced by a series of functions that you test before? makes more sense to me that this output is generated by tests, rather than being put there manually

Comment: Your tests should be independent of each other. Otherwise, they’re not really two tests; they’re one test that’s spread out. Your testing harness can use functions like setUp and tearDown for any side effects needed before an actual test is run. (Your question is actually completely answered by @Soviut below.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The order tests run in shouldn't matter since tests, and your code, should be atomic. Meaning newer tests aren't affected by older tests; They're completely isolated from each other. This makes it possible to run test suites in parallel to speed up test running.

The tests will most likely run in alphanumeric order based on the file name. This would be further affected by the directory structure and how those directories are named as well. This may even be different depending on your operating system.

Rather than speculate, you should simply create your tests and run them, then see which order they ran in. If your test suite has a parallel or async option turned on, there's a good chance no two test runs will happen in the same order twice.

Comment: Thanks. Nice explanation, It helps me a lot.